# "container started" event of a pod from kubernetes using pythons kubernetes library

Tags: python-2.7, kubernetes

I've a deployment with one container having postStart hook as shown below

```
      containers:
      - name: openvas
        image: my-image:test
        lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                 command:
                 - /usr/local/tools/is_service_ready.sh
```

I'm watching for the events for pods using python's kubernetes library.
when the pod gets deployed, container comes up and postStart script will be executed until postStart script exits successfully. I want to get the event from kubernetes using pythons kubernetes library when CONTAINER comes up.
I tried watching the event, I get the event with status as 'containersReady' only when postStart completes and the POD comes up,it can be seen below.

```
 'status': {'conditions': [{'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 25, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                            'message': None,
                            'reason': None,
                            'status': 'True',
                            'type': 'Initialized'},
                           {'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 26, 51, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                            'message': None,
                            'reason': None,
                            'status': 'True',
                            'type': 'Ready'},
                           {'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': None,
                            'message': None,
                            'reason': None,
                            'status': 'True',
                            'type': 'ContainersReady'},
                           {'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 25, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                            'message': None,
                            'reason': None,
                            'status': 'True',
                            'type': 'PodScheduled'}],
                       'container_statuses': [{'container_id': 'docker://1c39e13dc777a34c38d4194edc23c3668697223746b60276acffe3d62f9f0c44',
                                    'image': 'my-image:test',
                                    'image_id': 'docker://sha256:9903437699d871c1f3af7958a7294fe419ed7b1076cdb8e839687e67501b301b',
                                    'last_state': {'running': None,
                                                   'terminated': None,
                                                   'waiting': None},
                                    'name': 'samplename',
                                    'ready': True,
                                    'restart_count': 0,
                                    'state': {'running': {'started_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 25, 14, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
                                              'terminated': None,
                                              'waiting': None}}],
```

and before this I get status  'podScheduled' as 'True'

```
 'status': {'conditions': [{'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 25, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                            'message': None,
                            'reason': None,
                            'status': 'True',
                            'type': 'Initialized'},
                           {'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 25, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                            'message': 'containers with unready status: [openvas]',
                            'reason': 'ContainersNotReady',
                            'status': 'False',
                            'type': 'Ready'},
                           {'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': None,
                            'message': 'containers with unready status: [openvas]',
                            'reason': 'ContainersNotReady',
                            'status': 'False',
                            'type': 'ContainersReady'},
                           {'last_probe_time': None,
                            'last_transition_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 16, 25, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
                            'message': None,
                            'reason': None,
                            'status': 'True',
                            'type': 'PodScheduled'}],
            'container_statuses': [{'container_id': None,
                                    'image': 'ns-openvas:test',
                                    'image_id': '',
                                    'last_state': {'running': None,
                                                   'terminated': None,
                                                   'waiting': None},
                                    'name': 'openvas',
                                    'ready': False,
                                    'restart_count': 0,
                                    'state': {'running': None,
                                              'terminated': None,
                                              'waiting': {'message': None,
                                                          'reason': 'ContainerCreating'}}}],
```

Anything I can try to get the event when the CONTAINER comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, with current approach you will never get it working, because, as describe [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#discussion) :

> The postStart handler runs asynchronously relative to the Container’s
>   code, but Kubernetes’ management of the container **blocks** until the
>   postStart handler completes. **The Container’s status is not set to
>   RUNNING until the postStart handler completes.**

Maybe you should create another pod with `is_service_ready.sh` script, which will be watching events of the main pod.